# Tusken Raiders mask inspiration

Tags: star-wars, behind-the-scenes

Is the outfit of the Tusken Raiders based on World War 2 gas masks.?

This picture from 1941

[image: 1941 family]

Looks suspiciously familiar.

[image: Dave]

Comment: You know... now you say it Andrew Jackson looks A LOT like Greedo...http://howirememberit.tumblr.com/ (hint...next time REMOVE  the link from the bottom of the picture!)

Comment: The photo is doctored, but even if it wasn't, the masks would look more like WWI models than WWII.

Comment: @WadCheber the sand person photo isn't doctored. He's clearly standing in an actual desert environment, there's no green screen tickery.

Comment: @InguShama - Good thing I was talking about the other photo.  :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your question is based on a false premise. That photo is not of gas masks from WW2. It is from a site called "How I remember it" which contains doctored photos. [Here is the link to yours](http://howirememberit.tumblr.com/post/4551301515/the-raider-family-1941).

Here are another couple of sci-fi examples from [the same site](http://howirememberit.tumblr.com/):

[image: StormTrooper]

[image: General Darth Vader]

Real children's gas masks look quite different:

[image: Real gas masks]

Comment: Cheers for that. Wondered if it was a fake as the resemblance was uncanny

Comment: @ATB: to be fair, it is a very well done fake.

Comment: I got it from a Facebook group I'm on about old pictures.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. (I'm shooting for the reversal badge now... :))

Comment: Mummy? Are you my mummy?